# ActionScript: To perform non graphical operations

Tags: actionscript-3, web-applications, file-upload, actionscript

As I understand, ActionScript is used mostly to control graphical output on Flash websites: such as Flash based games.

However, I would like ActionScript to perform tasks not related to graphical output. Tasks, which for browser compatibility reasons, are more suitable for ActionScript: such as file upload.

Is it therefore possible to use ActionScript instead of JavaScript or to accomplish tasks that are not possible with JavaScript, such as file upload?

Are the following possible?

- Run ActionScript on HTML Button Press?
- Send information to ActionScript from HTML/JavaScript?
- Process information without any graphical output in ActionScript?
- Ouptut information from ActionScript to HTML/JavasScript?

I wish to know, if ActionScript can do what I wish.

I will have a picture of the right functions to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExternalInterface is your friend:
http://help.adobe.com/nl_NL/Flash/CS5/AS3LR/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Some tips when using ExternalInterface:

- set `allowScriptAccess` to "always" in the html embed code
- make sure the flash has an id in your html code

Some simple examples:

**1. Grab a value from javascript to flash**

```
// actionscript 3 code
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
  var url:String = ExternalInterface.call("document.location");

  // output to textfield
  var t:TextField = new TextField();
  addChild(t);
  t.text = url;
}
```

**2. Call a function with parameters from flash**

```
// actionscript 3 code 
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
   var result:String = "Flash rocks"
   ExternalInterface.call("alert", result);
}
```

**3. Call from javascript a function with parameters to Flash:**

```
// javascript
window.onLoad = function()
{
   document.getElementById('flashId').doSomething("javascript rocks");
}
```

.. and

```
// actionscript 3

if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
   ExternalInterface.addCallback("doSomething", handleSomethingFromJavascript);// links js function to as3 function
   function handleSomethingFromJavascript(value:String):void
   {
      // output to textfield
      var t:TextField = new TextField();
      addChild(t);
      t.text = value;
   }
}
```

You can do lots of stuff between flash and javascript, as you can see the intergration is almost painless! The only note is that within flash ExternalInterface is not available, so you have to test in browser. You can make a transparent Flash object using `wmode="transparent"`. You cannot use `display:none` or `visibility` (css) because then the flash isnt executed or acts slower. To make sure it keeps running, place it `position:fixed` (css) on the page in a corner or something. Browsers make flash object run in a sort of sleep mode (slower) when out of screen or when inactive (ie in an inactive tab)

Comment: Hi Mark. +1 and thanks for your excellent answer. I will use the functions above and I see that what I try to accomplish is perfectly doable. Because this answer perfectly and most completely answers my question, I am marking it as the *Accepted Answer*

Answer (score 1):

You can't really replace javascript with actionscript, but you can interact with it.

"Run ActionScript on HTML Button Press?" - Yes, this is possible through `ExternalInterface.registerCallback`. However, many actions (iirc, opening the file browser) can only be done on user interaction in flash, so you would need a flash button for that.

"Send information to ActionScript from HTML/JavaScript?" Also through externalInterface, or flashvars (but only at startup).

"Process information without any graphical output in ActionScript?" - It's a programming language, so sure. What did you have in mind?

"Ouptut information from ActionScript to HTML/JavasScript?" - yes, also through ExternalInterface.

Comment: +1, thanks for good answers. You asked me, "What did I have in mind" regarding executing ActionScript without graphical output. Well, what I do not wish is having to inlude a Flash applet, to be able to include ActionScript into my Webpage. I thought, that ActionScript was developed for the purpose of support Flash objects i the website, and therefore, it is unseparable from them.

Comment: Well you will need to have a swf visible somewhere on your page in order to execute actionscript, no way around that. You can't use it like javascript (directly on a web page).

Comment: yes, this is what I meant. But I think, the Flash object with important ActionScript objects can be hidden on the webpage, is that correct? In other words, it will not disturb the design.